# Appending components like Instagram's image-component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to understand the following concept instagram is using.

No matter your current location on the instagram website, whenever you click to open an image, this image-component appends to the body as a ReactPortal.

This means you're then viewing the rendered component of whatever it was you were looking at **plus** the image-component outside of the react-root.

The image-component appends to the current component for example at Route `../explore` or `../profile/xy`, yet changes the URL to `../i/:id`

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Instagram that well, but I guess you mean something like what is discripted in the following link:
[React Router - Modal Gallery](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/modal-gallery)

I hope it helps